# How does the UBCF and IBCF method of recommenderlab in R work?

Tags: r, recommendation-engine

The code for UBCF method for recommendation is 
`rec=Recommender(r[1:nrow(r)],method="UBCF", param=list(normalize = "Z-score",method="Cosine",nn=5, minRating=1)`
while that for IBCF is `rec=Recommender(r[1:nrow(r)],method="IBCF", param=list(normalize = "Z-score",method="Jaccard",minRating=1))`What does each argument signify and how do methods 'UBCF' and 'IBCF' work over a particular data set?

Comment: Have a look at the vignette: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/recommenderlab/vignettes/recommenderlab.pdf